# flutter adding a clock widget to column

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, qt-mobility

[image]I have to use the clock wizard in flutter which works fine if insert directly inside body but i want to use it inside a column but it shows error. i've tried to use it as another stateful widget and calling inside children of column but still got error. Any help..???

```
import 'package:analog_clock_example/demo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:analog_clock/analog_clock.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
//void main() => runDemo();

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
        body: AnalogClock(),
      ));
}
```

Comment: share your code and also output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would have thrown you an error because you could have not set its constraints. 
Try something like this,

```
import 'package:analog_clock_example/demo.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:analog_clock/analog_clock.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp()); 

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
               children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 300.0,       // Missing Constraints
                    width: 300.0,
                    child: AnalogClock(),
                 ),
             ],
          ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Make sure you stop and run it again and not doing `Hot Reload`. Hope that works!

Comment: to fill all the available space i think using `crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch ` would set it's constraints to the max width available

Comment: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: I have updated the answer! @AbhishekS Is that working now?

Comment: Yeah I tried SizedBox with specified height and width that worked. Anyway Thanks